# why buttons are not showing in frontend ui form in magento2?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

Why buttons are not showing in frontend UI Form in Magento2 ? Can anyone help in this.

**Code added in employee_form.xml file:**

```
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">employee_form.employee_form_data_source</item>
        <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">employee_form.employee_form_data_source</item>
    </item>
    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Employee Information</item>
    <item name="reverseMetadataMerge" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data</item>
        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">employee_form</item>
    </item>
    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>

    <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="save_and_continue" xsi:type="string">Magedeal\Customui\Block\Buttons\SaveButton</item>
    </item>

</argument>

<settings>
    <buttons>
        <button name="save" class="Magedeal\Customui\Block\Buttons\SaveButton"/>
    </buttons>
    <namespace>employee_form</namespace>
    <dataScope>data</dataScope>
    <deps>
        <dep>employee_form.employee_form_data_source</dep>
    </deps>
</settings>
```

Comment: please add more info in your question. Add codes you tried and or errors you get. In that way others can help you better

Comment: used code added

Comment: all buttons not working? or only the one inside settings tag?

Comment: all buttons are missing, none of them are showing.

Comment: add this before </argument> and check `<item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="save_and_continue" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">save and continue</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Save and Continue</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/save</item>
            </item>
    </item>`

Comment: thanks, but still no luck.